# jQuery AJAX request is not a function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need a second pair of eyes on this as cannot see why it's returning:

```
$("#message").removeClass().addClass(data.error === true ? "error" : "success").html(data.msg).show is not a function
```

My code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'postcode-lookup.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: {
            postcode : $('#postcode').val()
        },
        success : function(data){
            $('#waiting').hide(500);
            $('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success').text(data.msg).show(500);
            if (data.error === true)
                $('#restricted_locator').show(500);
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#waiting').hide(500);
            $('#message').removeClass().addClass('error').text('There was an error.').show(500);
            $('#restricted_locator').show(500);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `data.msg` is `undefined` then `$("#message")....html(data.msg)` will return a string and calling a `show` method on string will give you that error.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JrkyB/)**

Comment: if i comment out             $('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success').text(data.msg).show(500); i see returned results though

Comment: {"text":"{\"id\":\"2\",\"error\":false,\"msg\":\"VARIOUS, Brisbane\"}","data":{"notifications":[]}} is returned result

Comment: data.msg doesn't exist in that example result.  Just populate a variable with data.msg and do a console.log - you'll see it's undefined.  Passing an undefined value into text() will cause the error, as pointed out by @ShankarSangoli

Comment: @JamesBrandon - I hope you understood your issue.